# Ho do I get tag and classname containing a word in the content of html code

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Given

```
<tagname class="classname">content contain "Posted by"word </tagname>
```

My approach is this:

1. Get all contents from web.
2. Find "Posted by" words in the contents.
3. Get tag and class name which it has this content.

I need to find all posted date in various websites such as http://www.testthisblog.com/

HTML code of this website has some content which is contain "Posted by" word.

```
<span class="chronodata">
     Posted by
     Eric Jacobson
     at
     <a class="timestamp-link"  href="http://www.testthisblog.com/2014/05/documenting-tests-part-2-tester-leaves.html"  title="permanent link">Tuesday, May 27, 2014</a>
</span>
```

so I try to search "Posted by" word in content using this Java code

```
String url = "http://www.testthisblog.com";

/*step1*/ 
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String htmlTxt = doc.text().toLowerCase();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*Posted by.*");
/*step2*/ 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlTxt);
if(matcher.find()){
  System.out.println("Find a word!!!");

 /*step3*/    >>What is possible? can I get tag and class name here?<<
}
```

I use Jsoup library and this method should be flexible for other website.

Comment: `doc.text().toLowerCase();` and `".*Posted by*"`.... seems legit....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done a lot cleaner. You could directly use `getElementsMatchingOwnText()` method of document as

```
String url = "http://www.testthisblog.com";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
for(Element element : doc.getElementsMatchingOwnText(".*Posted by*")){
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Note that I'm using `element.text()`. This strips out all the html content and gives you the actual value. So in your case it prints out

```
Posted by Eric Jacobson at Tuesday, May 27, 2014
Posted by Eric Jacobson at Thursday, May 22, 2014
Posted by Eric Jacobson at Tuesday, May 13, 2014
Posted by Eric Jacobson at Friday, May 09, 2014
Posted by Eric Jacobson at Tuesday, April 29, 2014
Posted by Eric Jacobson at Thursday, April 24, 2014
Posted by Eric Jacobson at Wednesday, April 09, 2014
```

But if you want to print the date alone

```
for(Element element : doc.getElementsMatchingOwnText(".*Posted by*")){
    System.out.println(element.select("a").first().text());
}
```

Apart from this if you are particular about this site then you could directly get the span with class attribute of chronodata. This is the tag that holds the Posted By field.

```
doc.select("span.chronodata");
```

But if you are particular about regex pattern and you can be sure about container tag you could use `:matchesOwn()` or `:contains()` filters like

```
doc.select("span:matchesOwn(Posted by)");
doc.select("span:contains(Posted by)");
```

Answer (score 1):

it is possible; a way of doing this is apply that regex on each elements text and in case it matches get tag and class

```
    String url = "http://www.testthisblog.com";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*Posted by*");

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements els = doc.getAllElements();
    for (int i = 0; i < els.size(); i++) {
        Element element = els.get(i);
        String txt = element.ownText();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(txt);
            System.out.println(element.tagName());
            System.out.println(element.className());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24256837/642706) seems like overkill.

```
Elements elements = document.getElementsContainingOwnText( "Posted by" );
```

That comparison is case-insensitive.